# Clean up AD References to now deleted mailbox Exchange 2013

Tags: active-directory, exchange, database, mailbox

We recently separated one of our mailbox databases into three databases to better manage its growing size.

The migrations all went well, and the old database has been dismounted for some time. Today, in an effort to clean things up a bit, I deleted the old database. After doing so, I started receiving the following error in the system logs:

[image: screenshot]

> [Autodiscover] Failed to refresh Mailbox server for database dbb9bd73-1a38-4487-92f7-6e71bea7ac52 in resource forest . Exception: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.DatabaseNotFoundException: The database with ID dbb9bd73-1a38-4487-92f7-6e71bea7ac52 couldn't be found.
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.Cafe.MailboxServerLocator.ResolveMasterServerOrDag()
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.Cafe.MailboxServerLocator.BeginGetServer(AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.HttpProxy.MailboxServerCache.RefreshDatabase(DatabaseWithForest database)

I think it's pretty straightforward: there are some broken references to that now deleted server that are left over in AD and causing issues. The problem is, I'm still fairly inexperienced when it comes to Windows domain management and I'm not sure how to go about finding those broken links and removing them.

Google turned up some interesting results on recovering databases that you were not deleting on purpose, but the only information regarding this particular error urges the user to "check database availability". Of course, having the database unavailable was sort of the point...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure you have put this together by now, but you should have disconnected the database before deleting it.   ADSI Edit tool will help you **view** Exchange System Objects in AD. I strongly suggest getting another set of eyes on this before making further changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found your post when I searched on the error message. My separate Client Access Server was generating the Event 3008. On the mailbox server, I was getting Event IDs 4 and 16 every 20 minutes showing that the CAS was trying to authenticate with a *domain*\SM_*GUID* account that doesn't exist (because this was the system mailbox in the database I deleted). These all started after I deleted some databases in EAC.

I saw the comment by @blaughw, but it didn't make sense. There is no such thing as disconnecting a database, and it's not a required step in deleting a database.

Anyway, I figured since only one of my Client Access Servers was generating the error, maybe it had cached the Active Directory information that was no longer valid.  So on the Client Access Server, I restarted the Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service, which restarts most other Exchange services. After that, I received no further such errors in the event logs on either the CAS or my mailbox server.

Jeffrey Fox